# Android Instant Run First-time takes too much time to launch app after installed

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, android-instant-run

I have installed [android-instant-run](/questions/tagged/android-instant-run) introduced in [android-studio-2.0](/questions/tagged/android-studio-2.0)

I am getting problem while running my app first time. Its appearing with blank screen for a 5 to 10 seconds then after launching activity.

[image]

It takes time to run first time only for every application but why it happens that I don't know.

**Logcat : W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.package.name/lib/arm**

Comment: If your target device or emulator is android 6.0 or above, this happnes for the first time. All subsequent runs will be faster as per documentation. But I haven't seen a blank screen in my implementation. Are you doing some heavy operations in activity's oncreate method?

Comment: @drulabs no, there is no any heavy operation. Just loading data from db.

Comment: yes, even I get this on my Marshmallow device, In the Logcat it says Late-enabling

Comment: Me too, getting same logcat as : W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.packagename/lib/arm

Comment: try with instant run disabled

Comment: @VivekMishra up till now, what ever we did is without instant run only.. I want to solve it with instant run.

Comment: instant run in 2.0 is buggy. I would suggest to update to 2.1

Comment: Hi @VivekMishra, i'm unable to update to 2.1 from Android Studio 2.0. Can u plz suggest what needs to b done?

Comment: switch from stable to beta channel in update dialog box

Comment: where would i get the "update dialog box"? @VivekMishra

Comment: help>check for updates

Comment: it shows "Latest version already updated".

Comment: @VivekMishra, i updated to 2.1 beta 3, bt still the splash screen is delayed

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty for 5 seconds ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello I am also facing this issue when i update my Android Studio 2.0

This issue is resolved by changing minSDKVersion from 14 to 16 and change the gradle version to 2.4. This will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The question is already answered, but in my case, it is due to the strange issue with Android Studio 2.0 & 2.1. First time of launching application take longer than usual. This issue happens only in debug mode and not effect your released APK. Try creating a release build of your app and check. It should work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It's because with `Instant Run` enabled, Android Studio injecting some `dex files` to make Instant Run function run in target device. Because of it, your application will take longer times to run than it normally does.

To check it, look at your Android Studio monitor when it starting to run your application. It will show that some dex files been loading.

The benefit of `Instant Run` is when you change your application and run it, **sometimes** it will immediately run in your device target with short delay compared without Instant Run.

But the caveat is, Instant Run still buggy and it doesn't always work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Gradle scripts -> build.gradle (Project). Inside the dependencies block, replace this line:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'`

with this one,

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'`

Now, sync your project. After syncing your project, you will get some errors.

Go to gradle-wrapper.properties. Now replace this this line:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`

with this one:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip`

Sync your project once or twice and your problem should be solved.

Comment: ASFIK, to deploy android studio instant run, it is mandatory to have gradle version 2.0.0 or above. If we degraded the version we are disabling the "instant-run". Am I correct Partha Chakraborty?

Comment: To disable instant run you don't need to downgrade the gradle version. You can do that in the perferences of Android Studio. Just search for "instant run" there and uncheck the feature.